# Supress automatic messages in cmake custom targets

Tags: cmake

I want to add custom targets with cmake but, some of them must be "silent", because it isn't neccesary. For example, for clean custom commands:

```
// In CMakeLists.txt
add_custom_target(clean-temporaries
   ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P clean-temporaries.cmake
   COMMENT "Deleting temporary files"
)

// clean-temporaries.cmake
file(GLOB_RECURSE temporary_files "*[~#]")
file(REMOVE ${temporary_files})

$ cmake .
$ make clean-temporals
[100%] Deleting temporary files
[100%] Built target clean-temporaries
$ make clean
$
```

We can see that CMake prepares "make clean" to not show messages, but, how can I say to CMake I don't want messages in a custom target?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a minus at the beginning of the command you want to hide from the console.

```
-make clean
```

Answer (score 0):

To deal with temporary files littering your source tree:

- Encourage contributors to configure their editors so that temporary files end up in a  common directory under their `$HOME` (eg: [vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_swap_and_backup_files_from_your_working_directory), [emacs](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/BackupDirectory)).
- Encourage contributors to configure their global version control ignore files to always ignore the temporary files for their own work environment (eg. for git: [vim](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/vim.gitignore), [emacs](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Emacs.gitignore)).
- Additionally exclude well known temporary file patterns in the version control's ignore file of each project, to be friendly to contributors who haven't yet implemented the two previous steps.

If you do that, it's likely that you don't have to put an additional 'optional' (ie. highly environment specific) step into your build system and you end up with a more generally applicable solution to the problem.

As an additional comment on your example code, I'd avoid building in the source tree and use [out-of-source builds](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Out-of-source_build_trees) instead.